After Ubuntu 24.04 upgrade screen resolution dropped to 1024x768
I have an LG 32UN880-B.AEU 32" monitor connected to a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 graphics card on an AMD system. It was correctly configured in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS the screen resolution dropped to 1024x768 and Display Settings showed nothing else.
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550 (and a reboot) showed me that an older driver had to be removed (version 470?). Odd that 550 wasn't bundled into 24.04.1. Anyway, fractional scaling doesn't appear to work. I tried a modest 125% and no mouse clicks worked thereafter on various windows. Somehow I managed to revert to 100% which I'll have to stick with unless someone has a better idea.

I had the same issue after upgrading from 23.10 to 24.04, and from the latter to 24.10 (pretty old nvidia graphics card). In my case the upgrade had switched back to the nouveau drivers (which apparently don't work well yet, or maybe they don't due to my old card).
From "Software and Updates" (the blue GUI app) go to the "Additional Drivers" tab. Wait for it to retrieve the options and select the latest tested non-server version (currently 560). It installs it and asks you to reboot. My 1080p was back after that and fractional scaling works properly.
I am not sure what commands this process runs, but I guess it is something more than just the one you provided.

It tells me "This device is using the recommended driver" and there's no 560 listed. Executing "sudo apt install nvidia-driver-560" returns "Unable to locate package nvidia-driver-560". Thanks anyway!
